# "Geometry has too many edges" This is the which keeps on coming on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, climate, geemap, climate-data-operators

I am trying to extract the data for the particular country using the shapefile for the province to get the daily precipitation data. But whenever I run the following code error displays:

> ImageCollection (Error) Collection.geometry: Geometry has too many
> edges (2171869 > 2000000)

```
// Loading the data

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY")
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1986,1987,'year'))
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'))
              .filterBounds(table2); // Here table2 is the shapefile for the country's province.
              
var total_precipitation = dataset.select('total_precipitation');

print('total precipitation in Image Collection',total_precipitation);
```

But I can't change my boundary points as they are the predefined province of the country. I am stuck and unable to move ahead.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a Google Earth Engine limitation that can be workaround by simplifying the geometry - the following function will remove non-significant edges:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-simplify

example:

```
var table2_simplified = table2.simplify({'maxError': 1})
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY")
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1986,1987,'year'))
              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,1,'month'))
              .filterBounds(table2_simplified); // Here table2 is the shapefile for the country's province.
              
var total_precipitation = dataset.select('total_precipitation');

print('total precipitation in Image Collection',total_precipitation);
```

*maxError* can be estimated experimentally to get a trade-off between the number of edges and the loss of data.

After use, verify that the data loss is not too significant.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It helped me to solve the geometry problem.